# How can I have parameters and call back functions at the same time in MongoDB update() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, q

I want to have a customized callback function to check if the update() is successful and return a Q promise accordingly.

```
var myFunction =  function (name, email) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();

  MongoClient.connect(mongodbUrl, function (err, db) {
    var collection = db.collection('myCollection');
    collection.update(
      {'name' : name}, 
      {$set:{'email' : email}}, 
      function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          deferred.resolve(false);
        }
        else
          //console.log(result);
          deferred.resolve(true);
      }
    );
    db.close();
  });
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

Then the **caller** is:

```
app.post('/abc', function(req, res) {
    myFunction(name, email)
        .then(function () {
            req.session.success = "success";
            res.redirect('/');
        })
        .fail(function (err){
          console.log(err.body);
          req.session.error = "error";
          res.redirect('/');
        });
});
```

First of all, the `.fail()` function in the **caller** is always executed, why?

Secondly, I also need a `{upsert : true}`, how can I added it to `update()` function while keeping the callback function?

Answer (score 1):

I took at stab at this (and did some refactoring), here's the result (I hope I understood what you were trying to do):

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const updateFunc = (name, email) => {
    return MongoClient.connect('mongodb://mongo-database:27017/stackoverflow')
            .then((db) => {
                return db.collection('collection').updateOne({ 'name' : name }, { $set: { 'email' : email }})
                    .then((result) => {
                        if (!result.matchedCount)
                            throw Error(`${name} does not exist in database`);
                        else if (result.matchedCount && !result.modifiedCount)
                            throw Error(`Email for ${name} is already ${email}`);
                        else
                            return `Email for ${name} has been updated to ${email}`;
                    });
            });
};

app.post('/update_user', function(req, res) {
    updateFunc(req.body.name, req.body.email)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
                res.send('success');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                res.send('error');
            });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('App listening on port 3000');
});
```

Some notes:

- update had been deprecated in the mongodb package, it is recommended
  that you use updateOne or updateMany
- the mongodb package ships with a promise library, so you don't need
  to use the Q package
- the promise doesn't error when the there are zero `matchedCount` or
  zero `modifiedCount`, so we need to throw custom errors
- I took some liberties with the usage express.js to make it easy for
  me to test...so the response is not what you had in your example

Hope that helps

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you.

Comment: @tic30, glad I could help